# In ruby, what does "&block" do?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s this &block in Ruby? And how does it get passes in a method here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814739/whats-this-block-in-ruby-and-how-does-it-get-passes-in-a-method-here)

I dont Understand the `&block` part, what does it do?

here is an example:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  @messages << method_name
  @object.send method_name, *args, &block
end
```

Comment: Keep up learning, Brian, we're here for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the support Boris! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Blocks` give you an opportunity to state a callback to pass on to a method.

The `&` is  key here - like @pst mentioned, it "promotes" the block to a Proc and binds the Proc to the variable with the given name.

**With** `&`

```
def time(&block)
  puts block
end

time
# => nil
time { foo }
# => #<Proc:0x00029bbc>
```

**Without** `&`

```
def time(block)
  puts block
end

time { foo }
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
# Because & isn't included, the method instead expected an arguement,
# but as a block isn't a arguement an error is returned.
```

Comment: Daniel, would you please show a code example?

Comment: IMHO this is a simple and literal explanation, which is adequate in the given  context except there is an alternative way to supply a block as a parameter that I don't know of

Comment: Actually the "&" does NOT "promote" a block to a Proc, its the other way around... it converts EXISTING Procs to a block, so methods that take a  block can use them! (the Proc is simply a "saved" block), so you create it:    my_proc = Proc.new {|x| ...do something... }    ... then you can use it in a method that takes a block:     @my_collection.each(&my_proc)

Answer (score 4):

Answering "And how would I pass it to another method?" comment by Brian:

Like this:

```
def compose init_value, n=2, &b
  if n==0 then init_value else
    b.call( compose init_value, n - 1, &b )
  end
end

compose 2 do |n| n * n end
#=> 16
compose 2, 4 do |n| n * n end
#=> 65536
compose 2, 4 do |n| n * 0.5 end
#=> 0.125
```

This is a recursive method that recursively applies the same block to a number several times. Here, the block packaged into `b` argument gets called, but at the same time it is passed on recursively to `compose` method, while `n` argument is decremented by 1. In the same way, `b` could be passed to any method, like `map`, `reduce`, anything.

Whereas, should you not need to pass the block to another method, you could simply use `yield`:

```
def apply_block_to_1_2_3
  return yield( 1 ), yield( 2 ), yield( 3 )
end

apply_block_to_1_2_3 { |n| n * n }
#=> [1, 4, 9]
```

May the force be with you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still dont get it... P.S. I spent like 30min analizing your code... (...and Im new to Ruby...)

Comment: Can you show something more simple?

Comment: Brian, this _is_ simple. It is imaginable that you could pinpoint exactly what do you not understand here in the comments, but frankly, if you are having troubles getting this basic code, I suggest that you start at [Matz's guide to Ruby](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/index.html), while afterwards you can continue onto Zed Shaw's "Learn Ruby the Hard Way".

Answer (score 3):

It converts the block to a proc object that can be passed on to another method.

Comment: and how would I pass it to another method?

Answer (score 1):

when you call a method with a block, there are 2 ways to use that block:

- call `yield` inside method
- convert it into a `Proc` object by prepending `&` to it

with second way you can pass it to another method.

so in your case it transforms the given block into a `Proc` and calling `method_name` with it.

think of it as you can pass a block just like any argument.

Comment: slivu, would you please show a code example?

Comment: ok, that last line brighten thing up for me a little bit!