# method attributes [ajax,jquery,rails4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am reading the book Agile web developpment with rails 4.
there is a part where the products' cart is showing only if it is not empty, my question is the function in the view send to the helper only 2 attributes while in the implementation there are 3 parameters.

in the view I have the bellow code, which render to _cart where I have the cart show

```
<%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, id: 'cart') do %>
        <%= render @cart %>
<% end %>
```

the helper has:

```
module ApplicationHelper
def hidden_div_if(condition, attributes = {}, &block)
 if condition
  attributes["style"] = "display: none"
 end
 content_tag("div", attributes, &block) end
end
```

My question is the &block in this case receives id: 'cart' but is it a optional attibute? that why it comes with &. but what about attributes = {}? 
I am really not sure how that is happening, could someone explain me a bit?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code between and including `do` and `end` is the block, and this is the third argument for `hidden_div_if`, which is simply passed on to `content_tag`. The `&` in the definition of `hidden_div_if` captures the block in your view, whereas the `&` in the call to `content_tag` expands it again to pass it along.

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814739/whats-this-block-in-ruby-and-how-does-it-get-passed-in-a-method-here) explains this idea nicely with a few examples. I recommend testing everything out yourself in `irb` to get a feel for it.

Comment: great I go it, I will try to make some test and let you know!